# Qt 5.4.1 MinGW 4.9.1 is with or without OpenGL?

Tags: qt, opengl, mingw

From the official Qt website, the package "Qt 5.4.1 MinGW 4.9.1" is meant to be compiled with or without OpenGL support?

I saw that in the MSVC versions of the same package, OpenGL, when present, is specified. Does this apply also to MinGW? Or it is implicit?

Comment: Qt support in windows is handled using the Angle library that wraps directX in a openGL ES2 layer

Comment: Is it true also with the MinGW compiled version?

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 If you hovered over the link you'd be able to see the file name is qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw491_opengl-5.4.1.exe